# RS485 problem, losing nodes

Tags: rs485

I have 5 nodes that are connected to a server with RS485.

The distance between nodes is 5.5 m. I used a shielded twisted pair cable and I terminated the line with a 120 ohm resistance. The power of nodes cable is separated completely. I want to collect a sensor data and send it to a server (nanopi m3) via RS485. The sensors and cables are placed under the ground.

The problem is that sometimes I lose a node. It means that I don't receive any data. But it automatically returns after some days. After that I lose another one and it also returns after a while. I think it is not the code's problem because I have data of first and second sensors constantly. the problem occurs for 3rd, 4th and last sensor nodes. The baud rate for sensors and driver is 115200.

The question is why does it occur? Can it be because of connecting GND of rs485 to the GND of the circuit?
[image]
black cable is power cable and the gray one is rs485 cable
[image: black cable is power cable and the gray one is rs485 cable]

Comment: Could you please post a schematic showing how your system is connected? Please be more specific about what you mean when you say you "lose a node"

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please quickly realise that this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows that you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which your post doesn't, I'm afraid. Please revise your question showing your work and findings so far, in considerable detail. Or delete the question if Internet searches give you your answer anyway. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: @DerStrom8 I dont receive any data. I lose the connection completely.

Comment: @N.Parsa Are you sure the baud rate is correct for the driver and the nodes? Are you sure you don't have some code on the node taking up too much time and missing its cue to communicate with the driver? Also, I still don't see a schematic.

Comment: @DerStrom8 yes the baud rate is 115200. We also checked the second question that you asked. I added a schematic.

Comment: @DerStrom8 Can it be because of connecting GND of rs485 to the GND of rest of the circuit?

Comment: Remember the MAX485 is just a transceiver and there is not a controller in your design. Can you clarify, which device is controlling your communication. Also, how is that communication being driven? Is a computer, an arduino, another circuit?...

Comment: @hyprfrcb it is connected to a stm32f103 microcontroller.

Comment: @N.Parsa where are the nodes in your schematic? I asked for a system schematic, not just one of the driver side. Also, it would be helpful if you used standard RS-485 signal labels. "D_A_P" and "D_A_N" mean nothing in RS-485. Anyway, the grounds of each node must be connected to the ground of the driver. If each node has a separate reference point then it may cause problems

Comment: The new schematic does not help anything. I say again, **where are the nodes in your schematic?** Show a **complete system diagram** showing the connection between the driver and the nodes.

Comment: Thank you for your edits. Are you able to be a little more specific about how your sensor nodes are designed and programmed? Same with your driver. This could be more of a code issue, which should probably be asked on https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @DerStrom8 I don't think that it is a code issue because we tested the code in lab for a month and we had all sensors. (but the distance between nodes was 50cm not 5.5 m)

Comment: @N.Parsa Out of curiosity, what are you using for a power supply? Are you powering all nodes on a single bus, or do each of them have their own power supply?

Comment: @DerStrom8 12 v, 5 A, all nodes on a single bus.

Comment: @N.Parsa Is there any way you could post a *photo* of your setup? May be more helpful in this case than a system diagram.

Comment: @DerStrom8 Unfortunately not. Because it is not accessible right now. But I have one of the nodes that I used for termination node.

Comment: @N.Parsa Are you using a twisted pair for your 485 communication? I can't tell from the image.

Comment: Also, are you 100% sure all of your nodes have different addresses? If multiple nodes try responding simultaneously it may cause problems.

Comment: @DerStrom8 Yes I said in the question that it is a shielded twisted  pair. And Yes I am sure that nodes addresses are different.

Comment: @N.Parsa Woops, missed the part about the shielded twisted pair (I read through the question quickly). Do you have an oscilloscope? I would be interested to see the actual signals being passed along the 485+ and 485- lines (at the same time). This may offer some insight as to what is going wrong. See if you can capture these signals when one of the nodes drops out.

Answer (score 2):

> I used a shielded twisted pair cable and I terminated the line with a
>   120 ohm resistance.

Just in case you have misinterpreted what is needed: -

[image]

You terminate the line at both ends - i.e. each end has a 120 ohm resistor. Nodes in the middle section do not have terminations. If you have a star point system then it's different again.

If #1 is your master then nodes further away will be more affected by a wrong termination. You should also consider that timings will increase as the furthest node is communicated with so maybe a tweak to your master software might be also worth thinking about in case it times out too early (unlikely I know but people put all sorts of checks in software).

If you are not using the cable shield to tie together your node 0 volts then you can have problems. You should have something like this ideally: -

[image]

The drawing above is like my top diagram but I have added a cable shield that locally connects to each node's local 0 volts. Without this connection nodes can individually pick-up common-mode noise from other equipment that superimposes on top of the return signal they generate. This common-mode noise can exceed the input common-mode range of the RS485 transceiver you are using in the master and give rubbish data.

Even if you employ the scheme above you may still fall foul of ground fault currents passing through the cable. This happens when sensors attached to a node's MCU also make solid or partial connections to ground at various points in the installation. If you believe this could be a possibility then you might need to consider using isolated RS485 driver/receivers.

Comment: At 115k baud I can't imagine the timing difference from driver to furthest node would be an issue if each of the 5 nodes is only 5.5 meters apart. For all practical purposes the same goes for termination as well, but it's still good practice to terminate both ends anyway.

Comment: @DerStrom8 I've had comms problems on this sort of length when a terminator is removed and that was at 9600 baud. But yes, the time delay is in the order of a micro second so it's unimaginable that this could happen.

Comment: I didnt put 120 ohm resistance for each node, I used 2 resistances.

Comment: And what was your wiring scheme that you adopted and did it have the 120 ohm resistors at both ends of the wire? Did you star-point from nodes to the master maybe?

Comment: It is just like the picture that you attached.

Comment: @Andyaka Interesting, I've been able to drive a node 150 meters from the master at 115k baud with termination at one end only without issue (this was before we discovered that the off-the-shelf RS-485 driver we were using didn't have built-in termination). Again, this isn't recommended (obviously). Oh well, better to stick with good practices anyway ;)

Comment: @N.Parsa does your master have a terminator built in or is it identical to your slaves hardware wise? Did you use correct cable (shielded twisted pair is best providing it is 120 ohm characteristic impedance).

Comment: @N.Parsa You never answered, do all of the nodes share the same ground as the driver? This is very important as well.

Comment: Are the slaves galvanically isolated from ground or could earth currents from other equipment hijack the cable? Are the cable shields connected to a local 0 volts shared by all nodes?

Comment: @DerStrom8 I used a resistor in the last node just like the picture, and the driver has a build in 120 ohm termination.

Comment: @N.Parsa: I'm watching this from the sidelines. You are not supplying the information requested. Read through the comments carefully and be sure that you supply *all* the information requested otherwise those trying to help will give up.

Comment: @DerStrom8 No they do not share the same ground as the driver.

Comment: @N.Parsa Then you need to fix that. **ALL RS-485 NODES MUST SHARE THE SAME GROUND AS THE DRIVER**. The only exception to this rule would be if the RS-485 lines are ALSO isolated optically on each node, which I doubt is the case.

Comment: @Transistor thank you for your attention but I have a little problem in english. I try to answer. and also I am new to community.

Comment: @DerStrom8 Thanks a lot. I will fix it and let you know.

Comment: @N.Parsa That's fine, I understand the language barrier. Use a translator if you have to. http://translate.google.com

Comment: @DerStrom8 I connected nodes ground to driver ground. First I had all the nodes but after 3 days I lost the last one again.

Comment: @DerStrom8 I found out that the problem of the last one was its sensor problem. Thank you for helping.

Comment: @N.Parsa Glad to hear you solved the problem! I didn't think there was really anything else that could be wrong other than the device itself.